# Docker: Trying to install PHP libraries

Tags: linux, php, debian

I am running Apache / PHP using Docker. Linux distro is Debian. I am trying to install php7.3-gd. I run command:

```
apt-get install php7.3-gd
```

But I get: E: Package 'php7.3-gd' has no installation candidate

so I have tried downloading the source to build it myself, but I need to install php7.3-dev, and this is either available.

So I found this page to [download it](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/php7.3-dev/download), I see I can add a mirror to sources, I add it and then run apt-get update and apt-get install php7.3-dev, but no luck.

Any ideas what am I missing?

System Info

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

PHP:

```
PHP 7.3.14 (cli) (built: Feb  1 2020 20:10:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.14, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 3):

Eduardo,

I've just realized a file called 'no-debian-php' at /etc/apt/preferences.d/ directory. I removed it and installed debian php packages normally. Maybe this can help after 2 years later.

Comment: Thank you so much. It finally did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 0):

That package exists, are you sure you don't simply need to `apt-get update` to update the cache first? https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php7.3-gd if it still does not work can you provide the output of `apt policy`, it sounds like you might be missing the Buster repository.

Docker images generally ship with no cache to reduce size.

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I try to run apt-get policy, I get an error: "E: Invalid operation policy"

Comment: @Eduardo Sorry forgot it's been renamed in recent versions its now `apt policy`

Comment: here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rb3iFtC8roD3kTy9goxYTOLrgFhJbY2e